# Laravel: (How) is it possible to link to a named route with a parameter?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have defined the following route:

```
Route::get('/tours/{country_identifier}', ['as' => 'country', 'uses' => 'CountryController@index']);
```

Now I would like to link to this named route using something like

```
route('country')
```

with a parameter for {country_identifier} filled in, e.g. '/tours/Canada'.

How can I make this happen?

Comment: try <a href="<?php echo URL::to('/tours/canada')?>">Canada</a>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass the parameters as second argument array:

```
route('country', ['country_identifier' => $someValue]);
```

You can take a look at the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/routing), there are a lot of useful examples there :)

Comment: All good answers, but you were the first :) I did not find an example of this in the docs though, but maybe I missed it...

Comment: I didn't find this in thee docs either. I saw it in Jeffery Way's tutorial on Forms.

Comment: @MichaelObi you can see [the class reference](http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Contracts/Routing/UrlGenerator.html#method_route) evrything you need to know about any method and it's paramaters is there :)

Answer (score 3):

To link from a view use (assuming you use blade)

```
<a href="{{ URL::route('country', array('country_identifier' => $var)) }}">$var</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

Its simple:

For a single link

```
<a href="{{ route('country', ['country_identifier' => $country_id])  }}">$country_name</a>
```

If you are generating some links you can do for example

```
@foreach($countries as $country)
<a href="{{ route('country', ['country_identifier' => $country->id])  }}">$country->name</a>
@endforeach
```

NB: Where `$countries` is model object passed to view example `$countries = Country::all()`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
route('country', array('country_identifier' => 'Canada'))
```

It will take 'canada'as parameter to route.